# I am trying to clean my data file from special characters with some conditions, but those conditions are not met?

Tags: c++, file-io

Here is my Code

This code is trying to remove special characters like ",',{,},(,) from a .txt file and replace them with blank space.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd;
    int i;
    int j;
    int len;
    int count = 0;
    int countcoma = 0;
    int countquote = 0;
    char buf[10];
    char spec[] = {',','"',':','{','}','(',')','\''};

    fd = open(argv[1],O_RDWR,0777);

    while (read(fd,buf,10) != 0) {
        len = strlen(buf);
        for (i=0;i<len;i++) {
            for (j=0;j<8;j++) {
                if (buf[i]==spec[j]) {
                    count =1;
                    countquote=0;
                    if (j==1) {
                        if (countcoma == 0) {
                            countcoma++;
                        }
                        if (countcoma == 1) {
                            countcoma--;
                        }
                    }
                    if ((j==7) && (countcoma ==1)) {        
                        countquote = 1;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
            //cout<<countquote;
            if ((count != 0) && (countquote == 0)) {
                buf[i] = ' ';
            }
            count = 0;      
        }
        lseek(fd, -sizeof(buf), SEEK_CUR);
        write(fd,buf,sizeof(buf));
        memset(buf,' ',10);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now i want the single quotes that are inside the double quotes in my file remain untouched, but all the special characters are replaced with space as mentioned in the code.
I want these kind of single quotes to remain untouched "what's" but after i run the file it becomes what s instead of what's

Comment: lord! tidy up that code would you! There is no need for it to be so damn unreadable.

Comment: What is this code trying to do? You should give us a summary of the code then tell us your problem.

Comment: Why the hack/heck do you need all those `@include`'s in the code shown here?

Comment: Have a look at regex.

Comment: ok i gave the summary. the @include doesn't create any kind of obstruction.

Comment: The lseek can't be right - what if the file length is not an exact multiple of 10 bytes in size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the problem with your code is that you are doing one thing, that you then undo in the next section. In particular:

```
                    if (countcoma == 0) {
                        countcoma++;
                    }
                    if (countcoma == 1) {
                        countcoma--;
                    }
```

Follow the logic: We come in with `countcoma` as zero. So the first `if` is true, and it gets incremented. It is now `1`. Next if says `if (countcoma == 1)` so it is now true, and we decrement it.

I replaced it with `countcoma = !countcoma;` which is a much simpler way to say "if it's 0, make it 1, if it's 1, make it 0`. You could put an`else`on the back of the first`if` to make the same thing.

There are also a whole bunch of stylistic things: For example hard-coded constants, writing back into the original file (means that if there is a bug, you lose the original file - good thing I didn't close the editor window with my sample file...), including half the universe in header files, and figuring which of the `spec` characters it is based on the index.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info) and other libraries.  (When on UNIX type `man regex`.)  You don't have to code this anymore nowadays, there are a zillion libraries that can do this for you.

Comment: can't use any of those libraries.

Comment: Ok, but why not?  You can use a lot of other stuff looking at your `#include`'s.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your code is suffering from a more general flaw than what has been pointed out before:

```
char buf[10]; /* Buffer is un-initialized here!! */

while (read(fd,buf,10) != 0) { /* read up to 10 bytes */
    len = strlen(buf); /* What happens here if no \0 byte was read? */
    ...
    lseek(fd, -sizeof(buf), SEEK_CUR); /* skip sizeof(buf) = 10 bytes anyway */
    write(fd,buf,sizeof(buf));         /* write sizeof(buf) = 10 bytes anyway */
    memset(buf,' ',10);                /* initialize buf to contain all spaces
                                          but no \0, so strlen will still result in
                                          reading past the array bounds */
```